# Realm Item appears twice when added to Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, cocoapods

I am developing an app where you can add items to a Table View using the Realm Database. At the moment, I can add an Item to the Table View but it's being added twice to the Realm Database. This then means that if I shut my app & then go back into it, the new Item I had previously added appears twice, once in the new position & once replacing the item which was in the table view just above it. Attached is my code. I've tried various different things but just can't figure out how to fix it. Thank you for your help!

This is the code where I am adding the item to my Table View/Realm Database:

```
extension MainTableViewController {

func createNewEventAlertView () {

    let newEventAlert = PMAlertController(title: "New Event Alert", description: "", image: nil, style: .alert)
    newEventAlert.addTextField { (eventNameAlertTextField) in
        eventNameAlertTextField?.placeholder = "Event Name"
        eventNameAlertTextField?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        eventNameAlertTextField?.textAlignment = .center
        eventNameAlertTextField?.text! = nameOfEvent.text!
        nameOfEvent = eventNameAlertTextField!
    }
    newEventAlert.addTextField { (dayEventDateTextField) in
        dayEventDateTextField?.placeholder = "Day Of The Month"
        dayEventDateTextField?.inputView = dayPickerView
        dayOfEvent = dayEventDateTextField!
    }
    newEventAlert.addTextField { (monthEventDateTextField) in
        monthEventDateTextField?.placeholder = "Month"
        monthEventDateTextField?.inputView = monthPickerView
        monthOfEvent = monthEventDateTextField!
    }
    newEventAlert.addTextField { (remindOneDayBeforeTextField) in
        remindOneDayBeforeTextField?.placeholder = "Remind 1 Day Before?"
        remindOneDayBeforeTextField?.inputView = oneDayPickerView
        oneDayReminder = remindOneDayBeforeTextField!
    }
    newEventAlert.addTextField { (remindSevenDaysBeforeTextField) in
        remindSevenDaysBeforeTextField?.placeholder = "Remind 7 Days Before?"
        remindSevenDaysBeforeTextField?.inputView = sevenDayPickerView
        sevenDayReminder = remindSevenDaysBeforeTextField!
    }


    newEventAlert.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, action: {
        print("Add Event Button Pressed in Alert")

        //Adding realmEventItem & its variables to the Database
        try! realm.write {
            //Adding the name & date of the Event to the Realm Database Item
            self.realmEventItem.nameOfEventRealm = self.nameOfEvent.text!
            let fullDateOfEvent = self.dayOfEvent.text! + " " + self.monthOfEvent.text!
            self.realmEventItem.dateOfEventRealm = fullDateOfEvent

            //Telling the Realm Database whether they wan't to be reminded one & seven days before the event
            if self.oneDayReminder.text == "Yes" {
                self.realmEventItem.oneDayBeforeReminderRealm = true
            } else {self.realmEventItem.oneDayBeforeReminderRealm = false}

            if self.sevenDayReminder.text == "Yes" {
                self.realmEventItem.sevenDaysBeforeReminderRealm = true
            } else {self.realmEventItem.sevenDaysBeforeReminderRealm = false}


            // Making Sure there is something written in the Name & Date Text Fields before allowing anything to be added
            if self.nameOfEvent.text != "" && self.dayOfEvent.text != "" && self.monthOfEvent.text != "" {
                    /*
                     - use create method instead of add method to add new entries,
                     - Because add method replaces last new entry with our previous entry,
                     - so every time only one object store in database
                     */


                realm.create(RealmEventItem.self, value: self.realmEventItem, update: false)
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: realmEventList.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

                //By Adding the follwing line it has meant that my code no longer crashes when I add an Item, then delete it & then try and add another item again.
                self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: realmEventList.count)
                print(realmEventList.count)


                self.labelWhenTableViewIsEmpty.text = ""
                    print("Add to Table View Called")

            } else {
                // Missing Boxes
                print("Missing Information!")
            }


            // This makes sure that each time the user goes to add a new Event all the picker are reset
            if self.nameOfEvent.text != "" { self.nameOfEvent.text = "" }
            if self.dayPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) != 0 { self.dayPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false) }
            if self.monthPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) != 0 {self.monthPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)}
            if self.oneDayPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) != 0 {self.oneDayPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)}
            if self.sevenDayPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) != 0 {self.sevenDayPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)}
        }


        print("REAL DATA:::-- \(realm.objects(RealmEventItem.self))")
    }))

    newEventAlert.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, action: {
        print("Cancel Button Pressed in Alert")
    }))

    present(newEventAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem by using a new variable of type RealmEventItem()
The Code Changed (which is inside try! realm.write) is now as follows:

```
 try! realm.write {

           //The concept of adding a newEventItem of type RealmEventItem() & and then adding all the values to it rather than direct to the RealmEventItem() fixed the problem of the new items replacing the previous ones.
            let newEventItem = RealmEventItem()

            // Joining the Day & Month Together
            let fullDateOfEvent = self.dayOfEvent.text! + " " + self.monthOfEvent.text!
            // Making Variables to give a boolean of whether the user would like reminders
            var oneDayReminderItem = false
            var sevenDayReminderItem = false

            if self.oneDayReminder.text == "Yes" {
                oneDayReminderItem = true
            } else {oneDayReminderItem = false}

            if self.sevenDayReminder.text == "Yes" {
                sevenDayReminderItem = true
            } else {sevenDayReminderItem = false}

            //Setting the values to the newEventItem --> which is part of the RealmEventItem()
            newEventItem.nameOfEventRealm = self.nameOfEvent.text!
            newEventItem.dateOfEventRealm = fullDateOfEvent
            newEventItem.oneDayBeforeReminderRealm = oneDayReminderItem
            newEventItem.sevenDaysBeforeReminderRealm = sevenDayReminderItem


            // Making Sure there is something written in the Name & Date Text Fields before allowing anything to be added
            if self.nameOfEvent.text != "" && self.dayOfEvent.text != "" && self.monthOfEvent.text != "" {
                    /*
                     - use create method instead of add method to add new entries,
                     - Because add method replaces last new entry with our previous entry,
                     - so every time only one object store in database
                     */
                //realm.add(newEventItem, update: false)
                realm.create(RealmEventItem.self, value: newEventItem, update: false)
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: realmEventList.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

                //By Adding the following line it has meant that my code no longer crashes when I add an Item, then delete it & then try and add another item again.
                self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: realmEventList.count)
                print(realmEventList.count)


                self.labelWhenTableViewIsEmpty.text = ""
                    print("Add to Table View Called")

            } else {
                // Missing Boxes
                print("Missing Information!")
            }
            }
```

Hope this can help someone in the future!